Scala Function Variables and Usage Of => and _
I am a newbie in Scala and found it pretty interesting btw. But I am not able get some of its syntactic sugar and the internal meaning why it's working at a place and not in another instance. For example Below are the two
A) val sumFunction: (Int,Int) => Int = _ + _
B) val mulFunc = (a: Int, b: Int) => _ * _
I am just curious to understand why _ is not working in case of B?
C) val sumFunction2: (a: Int, b: Int) => Int = _ + _
D) val mulFunc2 = (a: Int, b: Int) => a * b
Also what is the usage difference of => in C and D?

My personal advice, try to avoid the _ syntax since it can cause issues outside of very simple code.
But, let's try to explain what happens in each case and maybe that will clear things up.
A
val sumFunction: (Int,Int) => Int = _ + _

Here we define an immutable variable named sumFunction whose type is (Int, Int) => Int, in Englih words:

A function of two arguments, both of type Int, that returns an Int

And then the body / implementation is the expression _ + _ - The compiler expands that as:
(x, y) => x + y

In other words, the _ sugar syntax expands each _ as a new parameter of a lambda in the innermost scope.
And then, the body type checks with the provided type.
B
val mulFunc = (a: Int, b: Int) => _ * _

In this case, you don't provide a type for the val mulFunc but rather you let the compile infer it.
And here the sugar syntax expands like:
(a: Int, b: Int) => (x, y) => x * y

So you have a function of two parameters, that ignores those parameters, and then returns a new function. And, the compiler actually doesn't have enough information to infer the types.
C
val sumFunction2: (a: Int, b: Int) => Int = _ + _

This is simply bad syntax. Scala doesn't provide any way to define parameter names at the type level.
D
val mulFunc2 = (a: Int, b: Int) => a * b

This is just defining an immutable value called mulFunc2 and letting the compiler infer the type.
Then, we say that the expression to which it refers is the lambda (a: Int, b: Int) => a * b
The compiler then is able to infer the type of mulFunc2 as (Int, Int) => Int

Personally, I would go with D.
